# Как передать данные из DialogFragment в другой фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите как можно передать данные из DialogFragment в другой фрагмент. У меня есть программа. Там 3 таба (я имею ввиду вкладки реализованные через TabLayout) - секундомер, таймер, список таймеров. Каждый таб это фрагмент. Все 3 таба находятся в главном активити программы. 
Так вот. Я создал для таба с таймером DialogFragment, в котором с помощью NumberPicker'ов передаются минуты и секунды. И мне нужно когда я выставлю нужное время и нажму кнопку **ОК** в диалоге, передать переменную с данными пикеров во фрагмент таймера. То есть из DialogFragment данные нужно доставить до FragmentTimer (это фрагмент в котором реализован код таймера).
Я прочитал, что фрагменты не должны работать напрямую друг с другом. То есть мне надо передать данные в MainActivity, а оттуда передать их в FragmentTimer.

Подскажите какие методы для этого используются?

Код моего диалога такой:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

import club.fortress.timerstopwatch.R;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private int mMin;
    private int mSec;
    private int mValue = mMin + mSec; // Значение mValue мне и надо передать в активити
                                      // А из него в фрагмент FragmentTimer

    public interface MyDialogListener {
        void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment);
        void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment);
    }

    private MyDialogListener mListener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_timer, null);

        // Инициализируем пикеры и настраиваем их как надо
        NumberPicker numberPickerMin = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMin);
        NumberPicker numberPickerSec = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerSec);

        numberPickerMin.setMaxValue(60);
        numberPickerMin.setMinValue(0);
        numberPickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                mPickerValueMin = newVal * 60;
            }
        });
        numberPickerSec.setMaxValue(60);
        numberPickerSec.setMinValue(0);
        numberPickerSec.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                mPickerValueSec = newVal;
            }
        });

        builder.setTitle(R.string.set_time)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.set, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(MyDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(MyDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mListener = (MyDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

В активити у меня есть два метода для кнопок диалога **OK** и **Cancel**

```
    @Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You've pressed button \"OK\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You've pressed button \"Cancel\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Подскажите что делать дальше или может что-то переделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте еще параметры в методы:

```
void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment);
void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment);
```

Например:

```
public interface MyDialogListener {
    void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment, String myParm1);
    void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment, String myParm2);
}
```

И пихайте на здоровье в `myParm1` и `myParm2` что хотите.

Можно применить тип параметра `Bundle`, тогда в пакуйте в `Bundle` несколько параметров.

Comment: Спасибо! В активити передал значение, а в другой фрагмент из активити как правильно передать?

Comment: Для запуска `Fragment`'а положено вызывать статическую функцию типа `newInstance()` с параметрами, а далее `newInstance()` создает фрагмент и передает эти параметры через аргументы (в виде `Bundle`). Например [см. здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)